# Find the dimension of this vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I took the following question from Zhang, Fuzhen. Linear Algebra (Johns Hopkins Studies in the Mathematical Sciences)

> Find a basis and the dimension for the following vector space:
>   The space of all real polynomials in $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$ , where
>   $A=\left[\begin{matrix}
> 1 & 0&0\\
> 0 & \omega & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & \omega^2 \\
> \end{matrix}\right]$ and $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$
>
> For example, $A^3 − A^2 + 5A + I$ is one of the polynomials.

The answer key says

> ${I, A, A^2}$ is a basis. Dimension is 3.

I have no clue on how to reach this answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about characteristic polynomials?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner  I will research that thanks

Comment: $A$ is diagonal, so the roots of its characteristic polynomial are the entries, so the characteristic polynomial is $x^3-1$, so by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A^3-I=0$, so each of $A^3, A^4, A^5, ...$ is a linear combination of $I, A, $ and $ A^2$

Answer (score 5):

Hints: first verify that $\omega^{3}=1$. Then verify that $A^{3}=I$. (It is easy to multiply diagonal matrices). This proves that the dimension is at most $3$. Now verify that $I,A,A^{2}$ are linearly independent.